# Does the google bigquery api have a "create view" option?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I would like to use google's bigquery API in php to create a view.  I've looked through the GBQ API documentation at:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/

and it doesn't look like it's a possibility.  However, the bq command-line interface does allow you to create a view, as in the following example:

```
bq mk --view='select title from [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] where contributor_id = 3894110' dataset_id.table_id
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Tables.insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/insert) with [view.query](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables#resource) property